# DNS setup and hosting multiple domains on OS X Server

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, mac-osx-server

I've managed so far to setup my OS X Server and host one domain FOR MY STARTUP COMPANY. However WE have more domains, and the technicalities are not immediately clear, we're not sure how to setup an NS record for the OS X Server so that we can use it for the other domains.

We're using Dyn.com for DNS service as we have a dynamic IP which changes almost daily, so our primary server domain is pointed to the NS values of the Dyn.

We created a nameserver (NS) record on our OS X Server under DNS. For example our server is reachable at **server.domain.com**, so we created a *nameserver* value of **ns1.domain.com**, am we correct? Does this become the NS value we enter in my domain registrar to point other domains to our server? Or do we have to create an NS value in my Dyn account?

Also, our domain registrar provides a NS registration option in my account, it asks for a hostname and an IP, should we enter **server.domain.com** or **ns1.domain.com**? How does this relate to the DNS settings on my OS X Server and Dyn? Which one of the three takes precedence?

Another question, domains usually require 2 or more NS records, how do we go about that? Do we have to get a second IP from our ISP?